# What's the purpose of separate curly brackets in PHP

Tags: php

Is it a parser bug, or is there any usefulness in using curly brackets like this?

```
$x = 1;

{
    $x++;
}
```

As far as I can see, it behaves exactly as if the brackets weren't there, so why is it valid syntax?

Comment: It defines a block of code. If you put an `if ($condition)` on top of it, the whole block will be executed if the *condition* is true instead of only the first expression.

Comment: See also the abstract on [statements and grouping in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its purpose is grouping operations for using in places where only one operation allowed.

`if (cond) foo();` equals `if (cond) { foo(); }`
`foo();` equals `{ foo(); }`

Answer (score 7):

There is no any hidden meaning. It is more about readability.

Check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php):

> Any PHP script is built out of a series of statements. A statement can
>   be an assignment, a function call, a loop, a conditional statement or
>   even a statement that does nothing (an empty statement). Statements
>   usually end with a semicolon. In addition, **statements can be grouped
>   into a statement-group by encapsulating a group of statements with
>   curly braces**. A statement-group is a statement by itself as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Statements cannot be combined like expressions, you can always put a sequence of statements anywhere a statement can go by enclosing them in a set of curly braces.**

- Curly brackets are used to mark class, function (methods in OOP
  terminology), loop and control structure bodies.
- They can also be used within strings to separate variables from
  surrounding text.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
$x++;
}
```

is just like

```
{$x++;}
```

which is just like

```
$x++;
```

They're to denote a block of code.

You can also consider this:

```
if (true) {
  $x++;
}
```

The code has valid syntax, and it would behave exactly without the "if" condition. You can overcharge your code with "valid" and useless code as much as you want.

Answer (score -2):

The curly brackets can be used to change the scope to a local scope. So if you define a variable in the brackets it won't be available outside the brackets

Comment: Only functions and methods have their own, local scope.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.